# Maven build works with Docker GUI running but not with the binary

Tags: maven, docker

I installed the Docker executable with `brew install docker` and I can see it in the `PATH` of `bash`:

```
$ which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
```

I set up a Spring Boot application with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
MAINTAINER ...

COPY dist /dist/
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY target/${JAR_FILE} /target/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/target/app.jar"]
```

When I have the Docker GUI application running, Maven builds the app and I can run it and see it locally. But when the Docker GUI application is not running, Maven is unable to build the app, even though it is in the bash executable, because it can't establish a connection to Docker:

```
$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
[WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
...
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
...
Caused by: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection refused
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.498 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-12T11:39:34+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:1.4.4:build (default) on project econometer: Could not build image: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does Maven use a different `PATH` than `bash`? How can I give the path to the docker executable to Maven?

Comment: This looks like the problem: `java.io.IOException: Connection refused` which means there is port which is not allowed or the wrong port (Maybe for Docker itself..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker uses a client-server architecture, and the "whale" application provides the "server" half of it.  On a Mac you need to have the desktop application running (or a heavier-weight VM like what Docker Machine or `minikube` provides) to use any Docker commands or otherwise interact with Docker.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. Does this mean that Maven can only talk to a server like the Docker whale and not spawn sub-processes like the Docker executable?

Comment: The Docker executable also only talks to a server like the Docker whale.